# ssh tunnel and reverse tunnel on same port

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a AWS server that I want to use as a bridge to pass a vnc session. I am currently trying to figure things out on my computer. I'm using putty to make the SSH tunnel and the reverse tunnel (using port forwarding), and netcat to write to port or listen.

Here is what I can do, each separately:

-Listening with netcat to port 5933 on the server is well displaying what I'm writing with netcat on port 5934 of my computer after making:

```
SSH tunnel: localhost:5934---->awsServer:5933
```

-Listening with netcat to port 5932 of my computer is well displaying what I'm writing with netcat on port 5933 of the server after making:

```
 Reverse SSH tunnel: awsServer:5933----->localhost:5932
```

If the SSH tunnel and reverse tunnel are running at the same time, I can't from my computer:

```
nc localhost 5934
```

it immediately returns without any message.

But I can from the server:

```
nc localhost 5933
```

and when I listen on port 5932 of my computer, it displays what is entered from the server.

Now, how can I make this to work:

Tunnel from computer:5934 to server:5933 and reverse tunnel from server:5933 to computer:5932 at the same time ?

So that by launching from my:

```
bash1: nc localhost 5934
```

and

```
bash2: nc -l 5932
```

the text entered in bash1 is also displayed in bash2.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have a similar issue where I run a local minecraft server but expose the port in the cloud, but I want my kids to connect locally.  I am thinking that maybe this is just how reverse tunnel works.  To get around it, I may need to tunnel a different local port and then NAT to the original local port.

Comment: Yes, I remembered that I could achieve it. Are you still interested ? I don't really remember where I put the solution, as I did a lot of other things in between, but I can search (and sorry for the late answer, I'm every day on SO, but oddly didn't saw your comment)